# Synchronizing queries (or events) in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to execute several queries in node.js and only if all return result update GUI.

What is common pattern for it? 
I've learned to fire the query with

```
var query = client.query( q );
```

and handle the results with:

```
query.on('row', function(row) {..
query.on('end', function(row) {..
```

Should I execute each consecutive query in the `query.on('end', function(row)` handler?

Is there a mode efficient method for doing this?

Comment: what query system are you using? does it have promise support?

Comment: I would look into promises. The basic idea is that instead of returning the actual result (because the request is asynchronous) a promise object is returned. So you can chain promises and return them up through multiple functions. That or use callbacks.

Comment: That's one way that will work, but it leads to so-called [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/). There are lots of approaches to solving that problem.

Comment: @KevinB It's my first day learning node.js. I'm afraid I can't answer your question now. will check, what a promise is. Thanks!

Comment: @Craicerjack Ok promise looks to be a "standard" approach in JS. (I'd use FSM in C++, one can't assume, that all queries will be fine, responded at first attempt, etc. )

Comment: @mrmcgreg. Ok, thanks for the hint. Just found out, there are many many ways to do it. Async, lodash, promises, ...

Comment: I prefer to use promises, but if i just need a quick solution for a temporary script, i do sometimes use async, depending on whether or not the tool i'm using supports promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) it contains a lot of useful function to control flow in javascript. In your case you can use a simple [each method](https://github.com/caolan/async#each).

```
var list = [1, 2, 3];
var iterator = function(element, callback){
    // Do your async job
    var sql = "SELECT ..." + element;
    doQuery(sql, function(result){
        callback();
    }
}

async.each(list, iterator, function(result){
    if(result){
         alert("Error!");
    }else{
         // Do your update on the GUI
    }
}
```

(This is a meta code not a real tested code)

Inside your iterator you can do every async operation that you want and when you are don you can call the second parameter passed that it's a callback. If you need to pass an error call the callback with a parameter.

You can find a lot more information on async website, you can also find other useful method like series or parallel.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning async! I've used it, it's amazing! Actually I've applied first async.series. It worked fine, than I only switched to async.parallel without changing anything inside the body and it works as fine but faster.